# after cloning a git project all files in intellij idea are shown as unversioned

Tags: git, intellij-idea

after cloning a git project all files in intellij idea are shown as unversioned. 
Can anyone tell what could be the possible reason and how this can be fixed.

Comment: Please provide more details about your requirement and code which you try

Answer (score 3):

I realise that this question is 2y old by this point, but I had a similar issue when cloning a git copy of an SVN project that I'd been using in SVN for a while.

These two things fixed it for me:

- go to Settings --> Version Control and check that the VCS for the root directory is Git
- In the .idea folder for your project, open up vcs.xml. Check that all directories, it has the label `vcs="Git"`

  (a lot of these were still set to SVN for me as I'd been using the same project in SVN previously. You'll most likely only want your `$PROJECT_DIRECTORY` to be under VCS & remove any other references in this file)

Answer (score 0):

The folder `.idea` is placed in opened directories to save options/settings for that `IDE`.

You can prevent this with adding `.idea` to `.gitignore`.